# Divergence/convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, divergent-series

how can I prove this series diverges/converges? I used all adequate criteria but nothing useful came out..any ideas ?

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{\sin (n)\cos (n^2 )}}{\sqrt n +\sqrt[3]n}}$$

Comment: What reason do you have that makes it plausible to believe it does not converge? My intuition is rather that it does converge since the summands converge to zero and are kind of alternating.

Comment: yep, you might be right so I edited the text

Comment: It seems quite challenging, I couldn't find any answer up to now. Could you perhaps tell us in what context you found this series?

Comment: some old textbook, but there's no additional text other than what I've already provided

Comment: If it were an integral, I would suggest integration by parts (multiplying by $\frac nn$, integrating $n\cos n^2$, and differentiating the rest) to yield an equivalent integral that converges absolutely. Will summation by parts yield the same result here?

Answer (score 2):

This is rather unpleasant, but totally do-able.

Convergent:

First, rewrite the numerator using the product-to-sum formula, as follows:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{\sin (n)\cos (n^2 )}}{\sqrt n +\sqrt[3]n}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{\sin (n(n+1))-\sin (n(n-1) )}}{\sqrt n +\sqrt[3]n}}$$

Notice how the numerator appears to be telescoping a bit. If you write out the first few terms, the pattern is pretty easy to pick out.

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{\sin (n(n+1))-\sin (n(n-1) )}}{\sqrt n +\sqrt[3]n}} $$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\sin (n(n+1))\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt n + \sqrt[3] n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt[3] {n+1}}\bigg)}$$

Next, since:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\bigg|\sin (n(n+1))\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt n + \sqrt[3] n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt[3] {n+1}}\bigg)\bigg|}$$

$$ \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt n + \sqrt[3] n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt[3] {n+1}}\bigg)} \leq \infty$$ (by the integral test)

...we have that the series is absolutely convergent.

Edit: Clarity.